# Woocommerce + GSuite - Transactional emails best practices? Anyone?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, google-workspace

I've lost my brain the last couple of days trying to find the best solution for handling my transactional woocommerce emails, so that customers and store managers (on G Suite at the same domain as my site) get notified of new orders, etc.

**TL;DR:** I have a Woocommerce and want the next e-mail behavior and I wonder what's the best way to achieve this:

- Have woocommerce emails don't go to my customer spam folders and get
  notified to store.manager@mydomain.com  and myemail@mydomain.com
  G-Suite email accounts.

  - Use the info@mydomain.com and "MyDomain" as the "from email and name" in WooCommerce. Whether the info@mydomain.com is an e-mail
    alias of my G-Suite email or a server side e-mail I don't care. What
    I don't want is to configure a new G-Suite email just to serve
    transactional e-mails.

So I'll describe my original situation, problem and the solutions I've read about:
When I setup the Woocommerce e-mails in settings, using a @mydomain.com email account two things happened:

1. Customers would receive the e-mails on their spam folder.
2. Store managers did not receive any e-mails whatsoever.
   We also have this context info that might be of help:

   - We are just starting as an e-commerce, so no big load of emails...
   - We use the cheapest G-Suite plan (with up to 5 accounts) with our domain in Google Domain, so I don't want to use one of those account just to handle the transactional e-mails.
   - So I found the alias option and setup different aliases to both send and receive e-mails. E.g: "info@mydomain.com".

I read the official Woocommerce email-FAQ, and a bunch of other links in the Wordpress Forums and Stack Overflow, I came to find this three courses of action:

1. Setup split delivery and let my transactional e-mail address run from C-Panel.
2. Use an SMTP Plugin and set it up to use the Gmail API.
3. Create a subdomain and set WooCommerce/PHPServer to send the emails and just use my G-Suite emails as recipients.

I've read tons, and find myself in a loop where I don't know what's the best, future proof option, but this is what I've tried for every option:

1. I desisted on the idea of split delivery as soon as I found the e-mail aliases option in GSuite.
2. I did activated it and it solved one of my two problems, customers were no longer getting my emails to spam, but the Gmail API won't let me change the "from address" nor even the "from name", unless I select the alias as the default e-mail address on Gmail, which is not something I want; and if the alias (set up as mailer) and recipient is the same, then GSuite won't show the email in the inbox, but in the sent folder (and marked as read). So If the store manager email (storemanagername@mydomain.com) has an alias used to send Woocommerce emails (info@mydomain.com) he won't be notified for new orders.
3. I configured a domain alias on my Google Admin settings as a subdomain (store.mydomain.com) (which generates a new email alias with that subdomain) then I created a subdomain on my hosting provider (pointed at nothing for the moment) and had my hosting setup the Google MX records for my subdomain.  Without the SMTP Plugin it does nothing, regardless of which e-mail I put in the from and recipient fields on the WooCommerce settings. With the SMTP Plugin things kind of work, using the alias@subdomain.mydomain.com as the recipient, as emails do arrive to inbox (instead of the sent folder) but doubled the regular mail and a huge postmaster notice, about how the domain alias "subdomain.mydomain.com" doesn't exist.

As a related note: Google per default generates a test domain alias which is mydomain.com.test-google-a.com when I use the alias e-mail with this alias domain recipient in woocommerce and the regular G-Suite in the from field on Woocommerce things pretty much work, except that my customers still get the emails to their spam folders. 
How would I setup mailgun or sendgrid to use info@mydomain.com as the sender e-mail address? Would that work better?

I'm not new to wordpress, but definitely I'm a noob at WooCommerce and email protocol, setup in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think you might exceed the G Suite [sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)? That'd push you towards the SendGrid/Mailgun/etc. solution for outgoing info@mydomain.com mail, with G-Suite accepting the incoming mail however you'd like. Though if it's important to avoid "reply-to" type addresses, make sure to choose a provider/plan that supports running off your domain (SendGrid calls it "domain authentication", Mailgun calls it "domain verification", etc.).

That will likely also solve that initial problem you described in your point #2 (assuming it was due to mail being treated as local-to-the-web-server).

If you take that approach, make sure to triple-check your SPF/DKIM/DMARC setup. And depending on which provider you go with, some of their WordPress/WooCommerce integration plugins are...not great. I've been working on summarizing the [providers and their plugins](https://www.mail-mechanic.com/dedicated-smtp-providers) if it's of any help.

And I had a little trouble following who needs to get copies of what, but there's the `woocommerce_email_headers` filter if it would be helpful to BCC the store managers. You could even do it selectively.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I will go with a providers solution, it seems way less hassle and future-proof; so I will do that and make sure to take in all your notes.

Also great post, as it provides up-to-date info in one place, because for example the free details of mailgun were not so clear. 

And yes I will configure a no-reply address for the mailer service, I just didn't think it made sense to pay for a G-Suite account for that use.